# c# check date is weekend or weekday

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DayOfWeek today = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
if (today == DayOfWeek.Sunday || today == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
{
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" weekend"');", true);
}
else
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" weekday"');", true);
}
```

From line above i am able to find if today is weekend or weekday

now i want to get the date from user input
i tried this but fail,

my text input format : 2016-10-04

```
string dateInput = dateTextbox.Text;
DayOfWeek today = DateTime.dateInput.DayOfWeek;
```

Comment: how is the `dateTextbox.Text;` date looks like ?

Comment: `dateInput` is a string, you need to convert it to `DateTime` object. There are dozens of Similar questions on StackOverflow *How to convert a String to DateTime in C#*

Comment: Right, so what you're *really* asking is "How can I convert a string into a `DateTime`?" - as you have the rest of the code already.

Comment: convert string to DayOfWeek?

Comment: funny ppl everywhere,marked my post as duplicate but cannot provide any link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` to parse your `string` into a `DateTime`

```
string dateInput = dateTextbox.Text; //"2016-10-04"
DateTime dtResult = DateTime.ParseExact(dateInput, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DayOfWeek today = dtResult.DayOfWeek;
```

Comment: ,hi how to check the input is weekday or weekend?

Comment: as you mentioned `if (today == DayOfWeek.Sunday || today == DayOfWeek.Saturday)`

Comment: @KyLim I don't know if you have 24h or 12h format. for 24 use `HH`, for 12 `hh`

Comment: hye master fubo,
getting error in this line DateTime dtResult = DateTime.ParseExact(dateInput, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
error message : System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: 2016-11-08   ,this is the content i get

Answer (score 2):

IMO, you should use some DateTime control instead of a TextBox to enter DateTime. till then you need to convert `TextBox` `Text` to `DateTime` object first.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTextbox.Text, 
                                  "YYYY-MM-DD", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

FYI, there are numerous ways to convert String to DateTime (google will help). All have their pros and cons. Use which best suits you.

Comment: (today == DayOfWeek.Sunday || today == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
cannot compare against dayofweek and datetime

Comment: if(dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)

Comment: @KyLim: So you need to use the `DayOfWeek` property once you've converted it into a `DateTime`. You clearly know about the `DayOfWeek` property, because you're using it in the question. Software engineering is all about breaking a "big" problem into lots of tiny steps.

Comment: @KyLim: Use a DateTime Control.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal DateTime Control able check date is weekday or weekend?

Comment: this answer is too vague since you don't know if `DateTime.Parse` does work - and _google for your problem on your own_ could also be a comment

Comment: @KyLim: No. With TextBox, 20 users can put date in 20 diff formats, with DTControl you can eliminate that  issue.

Comment: $('.datepicker').daterangepicker({
                "singleDatePicker": true,
                "showDropdowns": true,
                "autoApply": true,
                locale: {
                    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
                }
            });
user input is same format